# Why does the 'logical short-circuit' principle in python fail?

Tags: python, list, short-circuit-evaluation

Compared to the code below, does python's "logical short-circuit" rule fail? If so, why is it not working?'

`print([1].append(3) or 2)`

The result is '2',the 'logical short circuit' principle seems to have failed

`print([1,3] or 2)`

the result is '[1,3]',the'logical short circuit' principle is valid.

Comment: Please try to [isolate problems](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before posting. For example, if `[1].append(3) or 2` doesn't give the result you expect, then **check first** whether `[1].append(3)` by itself is doing what you expect in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Calls to `append`, like `[1].append(3)`, return `None` (they update the list, but that's not visible in this snippet of code). `print([1].append(3) or 2)` is like `print(None or 2)` which is like `print(2)` because `None` is false-ish.

For example:

```
>>> print([1].append(3))
None
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I was just learning python back then and knew next to nothing about its features!